# Fabricjs multiline TextBox selection issue

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

There is an issue with selecting multiline textboxes on fabricjs canvas. As you can see in the attached gif, for the first time that the canvas loads, the only selectable place is the first line, once you select the text by clicking on the first line, the next time you can select the text by clicking anywhere on the text.

[image]

I have already tested calcOffset but did not work.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Please reproduce this in jsfiddle I will surely help you

Comment: The text box object height is not being set correctly, it still thinks it's a single-line box. I'm not sure how you're initializing the box, but if you can set the height correctly it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - This would make it easy. if not then try to change text may be there any special char is reason behind this. ( just guess)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");


var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('Amazing Nutrition \n Melatonin 10 Mg, 120 Tablets - \n Helps Promote Relaxation and Sleep - \n Wake up Refreshed and Revitalized', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fontSize:12,
  fill: '#333',
});

canvas.add(iTextSample);
```

```css
body {
    background-color:silver;
}
canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"> </script>

<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=600></canvas><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it's not that simple. I will try to share the code to reproduce it on jsfiddle